Images resized in HTML are clearer than resized in photoshop
enter image description here
This image is another example I found, where someone resized something pretty small with photoshop, and also the same size with HTML
Does anyone know why this happens I can't find a good response on the internet about it, but I have the same thing where if I upload an image with at least 2x quality and let HTML resize it, I get a better result than uploading it after resizing it in photoshop, even with using any of the different sampling methods it has
I tried the above, and got a bad result
I've added another example here the left is the HTML downsizing, the right is me downsizing in photoshop as a PNG (since the jpg was significantly worse)
HTML vs Photoshop

Did you use JPG format with Photoshop ?

Yes but I was looking side by side within photoshop and the browser as well to check it before export and after export

Avoid JPEG compression of non-photographic images. This is not a lossless compression, and it always blurs the pixels.

So I've just added another example on the post HTML vs Photoshop, I used PNG for this and you can still see a noticable difference between the two, which is where I'm getting confused.
I assumed since the pixels are the same on each, they would be identicle, but they aren't

I would say that in the PNG case the difference is not so great. However Photoshop is designed for photos.
